# Setting a default sound card in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, audio, kali-linux, sound-card, alsa

I've been trying to get the audio working on my Kali box and it's been a lot of trouble. I have both a Intel HDMI and an Intel PCH card on the computer but both of them seem to be missing from the gnome audio settings panel but with further inspection I think the HDMI Card is getting set as default which is not useful for me as I don't use any HDMI hardware.

Command Outputs:

```
root@host:/proc/asound# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Case of the missing cards.

[image: Audio Settings]

If anyone can guide me to set the 'generic' audio interface as the default it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Red

Comment: Is Kali Linux using PulseAudio? Is that configuration thingy the same as `paprefs` or `pavucontrol`?

Comment: I think it uses ALSA. Have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Not much info above. I'm no expert but I had the same problem and fixed it. So this might help.

From a command line, type `rm -rf ~/.config/pulse` then reboot.

If your sound cards now show up in sound configuration, then your system uses Pulse.

I believe it uses card 0 by default. If you want to use card 1, Google something like "linux sound card" to find lots of ways to do it.

What I did: From a command line, type `pacmd list-cards`. Each card will have a bunch of "profiles" listed beneath it. Note the "index number" of the card you want (1), then select the most suitable profile for your system. I have 2 speakers, so my profile is "output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo" instead of 2.1 or 5.1, etc. Then add these 2 lines to **/etc/pulse/default.pa**:

```
set-card-profile 1  output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
set-default-sink 1
```

where "1" is the index and "output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo" your selected profile. Burn some incense and reboot.